# How to convert a json object into .csv file and how to export using Ionic 2 + angular 2?

Tags: json, csv, ionic2

I'm using a function in my angular 2 application to convert and export a JSON data into .CSV. The below is my function and is working fine in angular 2 application 
(web). The Same I tried to use in mobile app which I developed using Ionic 2, it is not working in mobile app. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

```
saveAsCSV() {
       let sampleJson : any = [{name:'ganesh', age:'24'},{name:'ramesh', age:'24'},{name:'suresh', age:'24'}]
       this.saveData = [];    
       let a = document.createElement("a");    
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');    
        document.body.appendChild(a);    
       let csvData = ConvertToCSV(sampleJson);    
       let blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });    
       let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);    
        a.href = url;    
        a.download = 'sample.csv'; 
        a.click();    
  }

ConvertToCSV(objArray) {    
        let array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
        let str = '';
        let row = ""; 
        for (let index in objArray[0]) {
            //Now convert each value to string and comma-separated
            row += index + ',';
        }
        row = row.slice(0, -1);
        //append Label row with line break
        str += row + '\r\n';

        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            let line = '';
            for (let index in array[i]) {
                if (line != '') line += ',';
                line += array[i][index];
            }
            str += line + '\r\n';
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: The "download" attribute is defendant on the browser on how to execute it. I suggest to download a file in ionic you should use this cordova plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "cordova-plugin-file" to export csv in Ionic 2.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

If you see the following error -

code:1 message:"NOT_FOUND_ERR"

Add one of the following lines in config.xml to resolve it.

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

As explained in the documentation of the plugin, you can use one of these two option to:

> choose whether to store files in the internal
>   file storage location, or using the previous logic, with a preference
>   in your application's config.xml file. Without this line, the File plugin will use Internal as the
>   default. If a preference tag is present, and is not one of these
>   values, the application will not start.
>
> If your application has previously been shipped to users, using an
>   older (pre- 3.0.0) version of this plugin, and has stored files in the
>   persistent filesystem, then you should set the preference to
>   Compatibility if your config.xml does not specify a location for the
>   persistent filesystem. Switching the location to "Internal" would mean
>   that existing users who upgrade their application may be unable to
>   access their previously-stored files, depending on their device.
>
> If your application is new, or has never previously stored files in
>   the persistent filesystem, then the Internal setting is generally
>   recommended.